# Speed up loop over each row for big dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, bigdata

I want to process a big dataset by assigning values to a new column according to other column values (two or three more columns). I have the Python code below.

My dataset contains of 17 million data records. It takes more than 40 hours to run the script. I am new to Python, and have only little experience with big data.

Could someone help me speed up the script runtime?

Here is the sample of the data set:

```
 PId    hZ  tId tPurp   ps  oZ  dZ  oT  dT
0   1   50  1040    32  762 748 10.5    12.5
0   1   50  1040    16  748 81  12.5    12.5
0   1   50  1040    2048    81  1   12.5    12.5
0   1   50  1040    1040    1   762 9.5 9.5
1   1   10  320 320 1   35  17.5    17.5
1   1   10  320 2048    35  1   19.5    19.5
2   1   50  1152    1152    297 102 11.5    12
2   1   50  1152    2048    102 1   12  12
2   1   50  1152    32  1   297 11.5    11.5
3   1   1   2   64  737 184 14  18
3   1   1   2   128 184 713 14  14
3   1   1   2   2048    184 1   18  18
3   1   1   2   2   1   737 9   9
4   1   1   2   2   1   856 9   9
4   1   1   2   2048    296 1   18  18
4   1   1   2   16  856 296 17  18
8   1   50  1056    16  97  7   15  15.5
8   1   50  1056    32  7   816 15.5    1
8   1   50  1056    2048    816 1   1   1
8   1   50  1056    1056    1   97  12  12
```

and below is the Python code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df_test = pd.read_csv("C:/users/test.csv")
df_test.sort_values(by=['PId','tId','oT','dT'],inplace=True)


ls2t = df_test.groupby(['PId','tId']).nth(-2)

ls2t.reset_index(level=(0,1),inplace=True)


ls2tps=ls2t[['PId','tId','ps']]

ls2tps=ls2tps.rename(columns = {'ps':'ls2ps'})

df_lst = pd.merge(df_test,
                 ls2tps,
                 on=['PId','tId'],
                 how='left')

for index,row in df_lst.iterrows():
    if df_lst.loc[index,'oZ']==df_lst.loc[index,'hZ'] and df_lst.loc[index,'ps']==2: 
       df_lst.loc[index,'d'] = 'A'
    elif df_lst.loc[index,'oZ']==df_lst.loc[index,'hZ'] and df_lst.loc[index,'ps']!=2:
         df_lst.loc[index,'d']='B'
    elif df_lst.loc[index,'ps']==2048 and (df_lst.loc[index,'ls2ps']==2 or df_lst.loc[index,'ls2ps']==514):
        df_lst.loc[index,'d']='A'
    elif df_lst.loc[index,'ps']==2048 and (df_lst.loc[index,'ls2ps']!=2 and df_lst.loc[index,'ls2ps']!=514):
        df_lst.loc[index,'d']='B'
    else:
        df_lst.loc[index,'d']='C'

od_aggpurp = df_lst.groupby(['oZ','dZ','d']).size().reset_index(name='counts')

od_aggpurp.to_csv('C:/users/test_result.csv')
```

Comment: okay.. there were one more ques similar to this one..i think there can be two ways to solve the problem..first break your dataframe into multiple chunks and then execute your logics on them asynchronously (asyncio would be helpful)..or try something like hadoop clusters..just a suggestion..arguments are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that loop you should try this:

```
df_lst.loc[(df_lst['oZ'] == df_lst['hZ']) & (df_lst['ps'] == 2), 'd'] = 'A'  
df_lst.loc[(df_lst['oZ'] == df_lst['hZ']) & (df_lst['ps'] != 2), 'd'] = 'B'
df_lst.loc[(df_lst['ps'] == 2048) & ((df_lst['ls2ps'] == 2) | (df_lst['ls2ps'] == 514)), 'd'] = 'A'
df_lst.loc[(df_lst['ps'] == 2048) & ((df_lst['ls2ps'] != 2) & (df_lst['ls2ps'] != 514)), 'd'] = 'B'
df_lst.loc[(df_lst['d'] != 'A') & (df_lst['d'] != 'B'), 'd'] = 'C'
```

Here you are selecting from df_lst (using .loc) only the rows with the requested parameters, but you are modifying only the *d* column.

Note that in pandas between dataframes *and* is *&*, *or* is | and *not* is ~.

If you prefer this should perform even better:

```
oZ_hZ = df_lst['oZ'] == df_lst['hZ']
ps_2 = df_lst['ps'] == 2

df_lst.loc[(oZ_hZ) & (ps_2), 'd'] = 'A'  
df_lst.loc[(oZ_hZ) & (~ps_2), 'd'] = 'B'

ps_2048 = df_lst['ps'] == 2048
ls2ps_2 = df_lst['ls2ps'] == 2
ls2ps_514 = df_lst['ls2ps'] == 514

df_lst.loc[(ps_2048) & ((ls2ps_2) | (ls2ps_514)), 'd'] = 'A'
df_lst.loc[(ps_2048) & ((~ls2ps_2) & (~ls2ps_514)), 'd'] = 'B'

df_lst.loc[(df_lst['d'] != 'A') & (df_lst['d'] != 'B'), 'd'] = 'C'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the suggested codes. But it gave me the error: _The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()._ for the code. I guess it may be because that df_lst.loc[df_lst['oZ'] == df_lst['hZ'] & df_lst['ps']==2]['d'] generate a series, so it cannot be assigned with a string value. So I used df_lst.loc[df_lst['oZ'] == df_lst['hZ'] & df_lst['ps']==2,'d'] = 'A'. Still the same error. Couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot some more parethesis. Now it should work. Yes, df_lst['d] == 2048 generates a boolean serie, but in this case it is used only to select elements from the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Really helpful!!! It only takes less than 2 minutes to run!!! But I made a small revision about the df_lst.loc[(oZ_hZ) & (ps_2)]['d'] = 'A' . Because it doesn't assign any value for column d. So I changed the code to df_lst.loc[((oZ_hZ) & (ps_2)),'d'] = 'A'. I am not really sure about the difference of the two codes. But the latter one works.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped! You are right! As they say here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy the first version sometimes works and sometimes not, because it may create a copy somewhere else.